# How to draw image from raw bytes using ReportLab?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pdf-generation, reportlab

All the examples I encounter in the internet is loading the image from url (either locally or in the web). What I want is to draw the image directly to the pdf from raw bytes.

**UPDATE:**

@georgexsh Here is my code based on my understanding of your comment below:

```
def PDF_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')

    ...

    page = canvas.Canvas(response, pagesize=A4)
    page.setTitle("Sample PDF")


    image = StringIO(raw_image_bytes) # raw_image_bytes is from external source
    image.seek(0)
    page.drawImage(image, 100, 100 )

    filename = 'document.pdf'
    page.showPage()
    page.save()

    return response
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

from [report lab Image object source code](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/e65e4addee32d7aff8a86cf46b3151b97f616390/src/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#flowables.py-401), filelike obj is acceptable, so you could wrap image data with `StringIO`/`io.BytesIO`, pass it as `filename`.

---

updated:

as you're using `drawImage` method, it needs a `ImageReader` obj:

```
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
import io
image = ImageReader(io.BytesIO(raw_image_bytes))
page.drawImage(image, ...)
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that? I haven't worked with `StringIO` yet. I am getting error like "initial_value must be str or None, not bytes".

Comment: Your answer still throws the same error I get earlier and the cause - as it seems - is `StringIO`. When I change it to `BytesIO`, it works like a charm. Please change your `StringIO` from your answer to `BytesIO` and I will accept your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @someone ok, i guess you're using py3.

Comment: btw, wkhtmltopdf if a way much better solution for generating pdf, i have switch from reportlab to it, saved a lot of work.